# Help with Php / Mysql form to delete books from db

Tags: php, mysql

*Anyone??*

Updated code The problem seems to be it isnt pulling anything from the database. Do you see any error in the php? Like nothing is being pulled at all. I'm trying *title* search for 'jQuery' and it isnt showing anything

p2.php

```
<html>

<style type="text/css">
input{font-size:1.4em;-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px; -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-botton-left-radius: 10px; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; border:1px solid #4186d3; color:#666;}
</style>

<body>

<fieldset>
<legend><h3>Delete a book</h3></legend>
<form action="p2send.php" method="post">
    <strong>Select a Search Type</strong> 
    <select name="searchtype">
        <option value="Author">Author</option>
        <option value="ISBN">ISBN</option>
        <option value="Title">Title</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="searchBox" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="send" />
</form>
</fieldset>
</body>

</html>
```

p2send.php:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","Jacked.1988");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("bookorama", $con);

// declare variables for select types
$titlevar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bookTitle']);
$authorvar= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
$isbnvar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['isbn']);
$pricevar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);

// sql queries to run depending on selected
$sql="SELECT * FROM books WHERE title='$titlevar'";
$sql="SELECT * FROM books WHERE author='$authorvar'";
$sql="SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn='$isbnvar'";


$res = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$result1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

$result1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

echo "Books to delete that matched your query:<br><br><input type='checkbox' name='book'> <strong>Title:</strong> $titlevar  <br> <strong>Author:</strong> $authorvar <br> <strong>ISBN:</strong> $isbnvar <br> <strong>Price:</strong> $pricevar " . "<br>";


mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: use `mysql_real_escape_string();` for data injection, and do a `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: I wonder about that sql syntax, is it provided by mysql_query ?  looks like an insert-statement

Comment: Watch out for [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Any reason why this question was down voted?

Comment: I think stackoverflow developer team should consider to show the id or name of the down voter somewhere around the vote section.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a few things wrong with both scripts. As kjy112 pointed out your `<select>` will have no value since each `<option>` is missing their value attribute. Also, in your associative arrays you need to put quotes around your indexes. For example `$_POST[searchtype]` should be `$_POST['searchtype']` or `$_POST["searchtype"]`. Something else I'm seeing is your `SELECT` statement appears to have invalid syntax. It seems that you're also trying to use `$_POST` variables in the statement that aren't actually there.

Comment: blank values in `<option>` tags are ok. the browser will silently take the displayed text and use that as the value to submit. It's not good to depend on, but it does work.

Comment: @Marc_B, Oh does it? I really love SO for that reason. I've never tried to do that but it's good to know it will work.

Answer (score 2):

A few wrong things in your code:

- `SELECT books (title, author, isbn, price) VALUES ('$_POST[bookTitle]','$_POST[author]','$_POST[isbn]', '$_POST[price]')` is not a valid mysql query.

This is the way to do a select : `"SELECT * FROM books WHERE title='$titlevar'";`

- You will need to fetch the results from the database with something like

  `$res = mysql_query($sql,$con);`

  `$result1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);`
- `<option>` probably needs a value, for example `<option value="title">Title</option>`
- A select will only give you ONE value for `searchtype` being either 'author','isbn' or 'price'
- **NEVER** use `$_POST[bookTitle]` straight away in a query. Always use at the very least `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[bookTitle])` to prevent SQL injection

There is more... but if you can already fix the points I mentioned, you'll be closer to something that works

Comment: I've updated my code, anyway you could check it out again? Thanks damp

Answer (score 1):

Please check your sql statement. It seems what your trying to do is a select but using the insert sintax...

```
SELECT books (title, author, isbn, price) VALUES '$_POST[bookTitle]','$_POST[author]','$_POST[isbn]', '$_POST[price]')
```